How to distribute provisioning profiles in the team for FastLane / TestFlight?
My team is setting up CI/CD for an iOS application using Fastlane. We are having problems setting up provisioning profiles and certificates. On my development account I generated three provisioning profiles:
distribution, development, and adhoc. How should we manage certificates?
Should I also create certificates and the private key and share them with other developers?
What the workflow should be?
Is there any way to leverage Fastlane tools like gym,  sigh and cert?
I would greatly appreciate your advice.
# This file contains the fastlane.tools configuration
# You can find the documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools
#
# For a list of all available actions, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
#
# For a list of all available plugins, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins
#

# Uncomment the line if you want fastlane to automatically update itself
# update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Build and run tests"
  lane :test do
    build_app(
      project: "moments.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "moments",
      export_method: "development",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "" => "Development_3"
        }
      }
    )

    # Add your test running code here
    # scan(scheme: "moments")
  end

 desc "Build and distribute Ad Hoc"
  lane :adhoc do
    build_app(
      project: "moments.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "moments",
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.moments" => "Development_Adhoc_1"
        }
      },
      include_bitcode: false,
      output_directory: "./output",
      output_name: "Moments.ipa"
    )

  end

 desc "Build and distribute to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    build_app(
      project: "moments.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "moments",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.moments" => "Distribution_2"
        }
      },
      include_bitcode: false,
      output_directory: "./output",
            output_name: "Moments.ipa"
    )

    pilot(
      skip_submission: true,
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
  end

  desc "Export app"
  lane :export_app do
    gym(
     project: "moments.xcodeproj",
     scheme: "moments",
     clean: true,

     export_options: {
       provisioningProfiles: {
          "com...." => "Distribution_2"
      }
     },
    include_bitcode: false,
    output_directory: "./output",

     export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
     output_name: "ReleaseApp.ipa"
    )
  end
end

